# JMeter While Controller doesn't loop SOAP/XML-RPC Request

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a JMeter script with

```
-Thread Group
 - While Controller
    -SOAP/XML-RPC Request
      -Regular Expression Extractor
```

**Extractor** gets **response code**, While controller checks if it's = **"200"**

`(${__javaScript("$errCode)== "500";)})`

And for some reason, it **doesn't loop**. 
But if replace **SOAP request** with **HTTP request** it's looping.
How can I loop with while  **SOAP request**?

Answer (score 0):

According to Apache's manual: "Otherwise - exit (or don't enter) the loop when the condition is equal to the string "false""
Apparently, SOAP/XML-RPC Request is failed and that's the reason why loop didn't start